# Squid3 TCP_DENIED/403 with TIMEOUT_FIRST_UP_PARENT

Tags: proxy, squid

I have the following hierarchy:

[image]

**P1** and **P2** are configured as:

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
acl localnet src 192.168.56.0/24
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80    # http
acl Safe_ports port 21    # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443   # https
acl Safe_ports port 70    # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210   # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280   # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488   # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591   # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777   # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16
http_access allow localnet
http_access deny all
icp_access allow localnet
icp_access deny all
http_port 3128
icp_port 3130
cache_mem 8 MB
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
refresh_pattern ^ftp:   1440  20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:  1440  0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .   0 20% 4320
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid3 100 16 16
client_netmask 255.255.255.255
cache_store_log /var/log/squid3/store.log
```

**P1** has IP `192.168.56.101` and additional entry `cache_peer 192.168.56.102 parent 3128 3130 default`

**P2** has IP `192.168.56.102`

**K** request

```
curl -x 192.168.56.102:3128 http://www.google.com/
```

Unfortunately I get on P2:

```
1413829721.803      0 192.168.56.101 TCP_DENIED/403 3770 GET http://localhost:3128/squid-internal-periodic/store_digest - NONE/- text/html
1413829721.807      0 192.168.56.101 TCP_DENIED/403 3641 GET http://www.google.pl/ - NONE/- text/html
```

and on P1:

```
1413829719.645      6 192.168.56.1 TCP_MISS/403 3743 GET http://www.google.pl/ - TIMEOUT_FIRST_UP_PARENT/192.168.56.102 text/html
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any luck on this @squixy?

Comment: Nope, I just dropped that project.